# About Locus ( Theory)

Tags: geometry

I'm literally confused about what a locus is. Can anyone explain me ?? I even searched the web and watched videos, but they failed to satisfy. Please explain elaborately !!

Comment: Why did you not understand them? Because, unless you've run into some sources of exceptionally low quality, you are very likely to find very similar answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "locus" is just a fancy word for the *set of points* that satisfy some condition, when that set of points is viewed as a geometric figure.

For example,

> An ellipse the locus of points in the plane whose sum of distances to two fixed points (called the *foci* of the ellipse) is a certain constant.

This means neither more nor less than

> An ellipse the geometric figure made up of all the points in the plane whose sum of distances to two fixed points (called the *foci* of the ellipse) is a certain constant.

Answer (score 1):

Locus is a set of all points on any geometric 2d figure.A set of points equidistant from a specific point which represents a circle.